# Column based grid (like masonry.js) using float and clear

Tags: html, css, css-float, masonry

Hi so I want to make a column based grid (two-column) using float and clear.

The idea is to give left block a float:left and clear:left, 
while giving right block a float:right and clear:right.

```
.left-block {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.right-block {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

But it turns out this is not working. Can you tell me why this won't work?

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/144nyyas/)

And why does this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/o0omhgmr/) work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the floating elements to get above the preceding element on the other side (because it's cleared). So there's no way to get the right stacking effect with only using floats.

For further understanding how floating and clearing works in detail I'd recommend reading the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).

The only way so far to get the masonry layout without additional containers is using CSS columns. You can find an example [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout).

Comment: but if you open my jsfiddle link, the first three left-block stack nicely while the fourth fails. that's what i dont understand. [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/o0omhgmr/) even works perfectly.

Comment: @StefanusThobiSinaga The position of the `left-block`s is defined by the height of the `right-block`s. A `left-block` can't be displayed above the `right-block` which is directly before it (in the html). The first ones on the left are only stacking up because the first one is pushing the other two on the left down. Your second example only works until you add more containers (http://jsfiddle.net/o0omhgmr/2/). It's more clear with smaller containers (http://jsfiddle.net/144nyyas/1/). If the `left-block`s would be higher than the right, the behavior would be the same, only on the opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just have the floats for the divs you're making and add the clear on the containing container so it blocks it out. This is untested off the top of my head but hope it works.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
}

.wrapperClear {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.left-block {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.right-block {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapperClear">
    <div class="left-block"></div>
    <div class="right-block"></div>
</div>
```